# How do I install Kivy on Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, kivy

I am really struggling to install Kivy on my Mac running on OS 11.1

I have been following the steps on the Kivy website, and here is the code I have been running and the error it has brought:

```
$ python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Users/*username*/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/8d/995357jn2y3_0znpn71tkxk80000gn/T/tmpgWNtOP Check the logs for full command output.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$ python3 -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples
```

as just tying 'python' will default to Python 2.7 on your Mac instead of Python 3.